# Transparent laser focus

Tags: light

Did I understand the answer [in this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/creating-volumetric-lighting-crepuscular-rays-in-cycles/2553#2553) correctly? It says that due to the fact that volumetric lighting is not implemented yet, creating a transparent laser focus with visible molecular spheres in it is not possible?

Right now I'm trying to see a sphere in a red "focus" and do not get the result I would like to have.

[image: A sphere in a very transparent focus]

Screenshot of the properties:

[image: now with more information]

Comment: If you want to actually see "little spheres" you might be able to try a particle system

Comment: I saw particle systems and did not try. So I may give it a try. Right now I experiment with transparency and do not get transparent effects. I add a bit more to the question...

Comment: The point is not, that they need to be "little" spheres. They only have to be so small that they can "diffuse" through the ray of light.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/making-a-laser-in-cycles-straight-beam-of-light

Comment: Do you want to do this in cycles or BI?

Comment: Is cycles not a part of blender? I choose the tool that does the job and I expected blender to be a good candidate to do a movie of diffusing spheres through a focal volume.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11075/discussion-between-stefan-bollmann-and-gandalf3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## BI:

BI *does* have volumetric rendering, so you could you could use two [*Spot* lamps](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Lighting/Lamps/Spot) with [*Halo*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Lighting/Lamps/Spot/Halos) enabled to get this effect:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*>Add > Lamp > Spot*
2. Select the spot lamp and duplicate it with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to  [duplicate linked](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication#Linked_Duplicates). This way all settings will be mirrored between each *Linked Duplicate*.
3. Rotate the duplicated lamp 180° (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>):

   [image]
4. Enable *Halo* in *Object Data > Spot Shape*.

Note that to get volumetric shadows, *Step* will have to be set to `1` or higher:

[image]

Result:

[image]

## Cycles:

Cycles does not yet have volumetrics integrated, but they are [planned to be in 2.69 or 2.70](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/Roadmap):

> **Plans**
>
> For 2.68, the following features are planned to be worked on:
>
> - Hair shader
> - Ubershader (combined diffuse+glossy+transparent node)
> - Look into of improvements for SSS, AO, mist, ..
>
> After this the next big feature will be Volumetrics. Probably the
> first release with Volumetrics will be 2.69 or 2.70.

You could fake this in Cycles by using the same scene with two spot lamps, but with transparent cone objects along with spot lamps to act as the volume.

1. Add a *Cone* and match it to the shape of the spot lamp:

   [image]
2. Create a material for the cones. The *IsCamera ray* node mixes the transparent shaders so that the cone appears to have some color only to the camera. All other rays will just pass through it unaffected. The *Layer Weight* node allows us to change the color based on how much faces point towards the camera.

   [image]

Result:

[image]

Note that with this technique it is impossible to get volumetric shadows. (see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2555/599) for some tricks to fake volumetrics in cycles with shadows.)