# Change custom Node input through Python console

Tags: python, node-editor, animation-nodes

I have a custom node simulating a laser: 
[image]

The node itself is pretty complex with rotations and whatnot, but it's attached to a Lamp object. In short what it does is illuminate a pixel if some conditions are met (mostly boolean checking with some algebra). It's based on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53548/using-nodes-for-laser-line/92155#92155). I have to create a demo to show the laser properties and how it can be tunned and changed. I would like to change the input values of this node (elevation,azimuth, turning around the laser beam axis and laser width/girth) from a python script.

How can I select and change the input values for this node and how can I set them depending on the frame number?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution using Animation Nodes? It seems you are asking about python but tagged AN.

Answer (score 3):

The group node in the material has input sockets and you can set the `default_value` of each socket. The `default_value` is used when there is no link to the socket to get a value from another node.

```
mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
gr_node = mat.node_tree.nodes['Group']

gr_node.inputs['Elevation'].default_value = 15.3
```