# Visible light beam with a specific shape

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

By using Cycles, I'd like to create and move a visible light beam with a specific shape, for instance, a pyramid. The beam should interact with other objects, without going through them but producing shadow regions behind them. In other words, I would like to reproduce the behaviour of a light beam impinging on opaque, not reflecting objects. I already created the shape of the beam but I am not able to assign the desired behaviour, i.e., the light behaviour. May you be so kind to help me?

I want to make sure that the light beam does *not* go trought an obstacle that is in his way, as example the iron barrell in this photo.
[image: : https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8l8M.jpg]

Comment: Can you give an photo example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: You might consider variations on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53548/using-nodes-for-laser-line).. it would depend on exactly the shape you were going for