# How to create an computationally efficient fan or sheet of light in Cycles?

Tags: light

I want a light source to put out a sheet or fan of light. It would illuminate only along a line if it were shining on a flat surface. But I want to shine this on complex shapes.

One way I've tried is to put a point light or emitting object between two closely spaced parallel planes. It can cast a line of light if I crank up the sample count to several thousand, but it's noisy, not well collimated, and of course slow. This is for an animation.

Comment: Check out [Rich Sedman's answer, here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53548/using-nodes-for-laser-line)

Comment: That pretty much answers my question.  Should I mark my own question as redundant?

Comment: It's phrased in a different way, so it might improve search results in future .. I think it's OK to leave it as it is ..you could answer your own question when you're done ... but I'm no expert on BSE policy

Comment: Rich Sedman's answer did not pop up in the searches I did. Odd, given that "laser line" appears in the title, and I'm sure I had searched for "laser".  Anyway, that's the perfect answer.