# How do I model Laser scanning effect?

Tags: modeling

So i'm trying to build this sci-fi looking scene and trying to scan one of my model but it won't give a decent result I tried using sun lamp reducing its size and blocking it with plane having a narrow slit.
[Here's the link of something similar](https://www.instagram.com/p/BmyJ_f-B9Zv/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link)

Comment: Just tried a plane as emission shader scaled to a thin rectangle, with a massive cube either side creating a long tunnel for the light to travel down. The light that comes out of the end is pretty focuses and looks laser like. Had to set the strength to 1000.

Comment: IMO, [Rich Sedman's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53548/using-nodes-for-laser-line) is a definitive answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have set a Spot light lamp to have a gradient that results in a laser line.

[image]

The Gradient Texture is sourced from the lamp's normal and the constrained via additional colour stops set to Constant.

The key was to up the strength to 10,000.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a really low poly cylinder in the shape of the beam (no edge loops between the start and end of the beam), two bones, one for the start of the beam and one on the object its hitting with an emission shader on the mesh.

If you enable 'emission' under Layers/Passes you can control how it glows in the compositor. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwAksU_hBFM is a fun tool for that. Thanks to BlenderBrit.