# Laser scanning effect in EEVEE?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, effects

I am trying to create laser scanning light in EEVEE for fast animation rendering.

[image]
    
An example laser screening gate from *Borderlands 2*

[This post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53548/using-nodes-for-laser-line) show the possibility to create an accurate effect in Cycles using node. However, there is no node setting for EEVEE for now. And I also need the light not shaded by the object but surrounding with it, like a 360° scanning rim.

Is it possible within EEVEE even with particle effect on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the effect you have managed with your solution.

You can use a shader in Eevee with the node setup shown.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VbgC.png]

The inputs on the left control intensity, scan (vertical offset) and focus (sorry I forgot to rename this one).  Thhis can be modded for different scan orientations using the mapping node.

**Ad endum**

Thought I would offer some explanation on this, it was 0400 hrs when I posted this so I was quite tired.

The magic happens in the mapping node (purple), basically I use the scale vector to squash the texture in the Z direction and scan it using the location vector.  I use a math node to scale the input controls and make them more friendly.

Then pipe this into a a gradient texture and onto the emmision shader.

I've added some white noise to give that laser effect (although this should probably get its vector from texture-node->object rather than the mapped as white noise shouldn't be squashed.

The rest should be pretty much obvious.

Comment: Is that a 2.81 version? The node seems to be more robust compare to `2.80.75`. I will try it on the newest build, thk for this concise answer

Comment: It is 2.81, but you can achieve the same in 2.80, it looks different because I have changed the noodle curve in user preferences also possible in 2.80.  I have also added some explanation to help you modify it.

Answer (score 2):

I end up with a plane with **Bool modifier** and **Wireframe modifier**.
[image]

Here is the setup:

1. Create a plane which is big enough to cover the object you need to scan.
2. Apply a **Boolean Modifier** with `Union` option and select the object.
3. Add a **Wireframe Modifier** to it and set the thickness to desired amount.
4. Setup the material of the plane with emission or something else that can light up.

**Result** (viewport render in ***2 seconds***)
[image]

We can also add a gate frame with properly setup to follow the light:
[image]

**Limitation**:
1. If the boolean fail to union the mesh, it won't show anything.(I fill up the Susanne eyes for the effect)
2. Emission with bloom effect is still not enough for a pleasant result.