# How can I make objects emit directional light in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I need to make a plane shine light only in one direction (or a very narrow angle range) like a spotlamp, or a projector but I don't want to use a spotlamp - I need a wide beam of light, that doesn't spread out in all directions. Spotlamp would produce a tiny cone of light, not a wide beam.

Comment: area lamp is not a solution for you ? can you give an illustration of what you need ?

Comment: Only light type I know in Cycles that emits parallel rays is the sunlight, I think, all others are omnidirectional and emit in all directions. Perhaps some vector math can do the trick, but I am not smart enough to come up with a solution myself.

Comment: See this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/making-a-laser-in-cycles-straight-beam-of-light

Comment: It could be easier to just model some mesh of the desired form which beam of lihgt should have. Then the mesh will be given some emission / transparent / etc. material and probably composited for finer effect.

Answer (score 2):

As you asked for a wide area :

Use an area lamp framed by an open cube (or another shape).

The lamp material is constrained by a constant falloff so that you have sharp borders on the light projection.

[image]

The open cube, is hidden on the rendering and diffuses nothing, due to this setting in its object properties :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've figured out a way to do this the way I wanted. I hope to make a tutorial about this soon.

[image: Node setup for the material]

Comment: given that the promised tutorial never materialized, it is hard to understand the reasoning behind the proposed answer.

Comment: It is actually pretty simple, if it facing away, it simply emits black light.