# How do I make a laser beam in Blender?

Tags: light, lighting

How do I achieve a physically accurate laser beam within Blender?

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: Laser Example]

Comment: Those beams look pretty digitally enhanced to me... But if you want a "physically correct" way, make a super direct light inside of a tube and use volumetric lighting

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53548/using-nodes-for-laser-line and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/making-a-laser-in-cycles-straight-beam-of-light