# How to create a laser beam in Blender?

Tags: modeling, animation, light

I am modeling a laser beam in blender, and I was wondering *exactly* how to achieve the "beam" look of the laser.

I don't exactly want to use a bright red lamp, or an emission shader, because obviously laser dots don't really change in size as you increase the distance between it and the producer.

Here is an reference image of a beam similar to what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

There are a couple questions similar to this one, but they obviously do not give information about achieving the volume of the laser, or the bright "star" at the end.

A detailed node setup for a type of projection like this would be the correct solution to this question.

Part of the problem: When I tried the laser lamp node setup for my lamp, it had no effect except for color.

Here is a picture of the lazer lamp's node setup with the model of the lazer case in material view:
[image]

This is in rendered view with a volume cube surrounding everything. (Lamp is still selected):[image]
This is my model of the laser case:
[image]
Here is the .blend if you want to work with it:[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/making-a-laser-in-cycles-straight-beam-of-light   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53548/using-nodes-for-laser-line?r=SearchResults&s=9|44.0767  and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazer

Comment: How do I achieve the star at the end? A detailed node setup for this?

Comment: I modeled the lazer *projector case*, and assigned materials to it. I also added the lazer shaders to the lazer projector itself, the ones shown in one of the other questions about lazers.

Comment: Just for reference, this is *NOT A DUPLICATE*. The other question associated with this one has to do with making the lazer dot, not the beam. I am looking to make the beam. I would be happy if you would re-open this question, as it may help future users of this site. Thank you!

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazer