# How to illustrate ideal refraction using cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting

How can a scene be setup to illustrate ideal refraction? The desired result is something like this (courtesy wikipedia):

[image]

In this cycles setup, a light projects nearly straight rays out (see [Making a Laser in Cycles - Straight Beam of Light?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/making-a-laser-in-cycles-straight-beam-of-light)). A plane is setup with a refraction shader. When the light passes through it, the outgoing rays are much more diffuse than the incoming rays.

Setup:

[image]

Plane refraction shader:

[image]

The result with the light rays::

[image]

How can the result be improved? Can the strength of the ray be increased after it hits the plane? Can the desired result be generated?

Sample Blend file - [image]

Comment: Hello :). I don't think that's possible, since light doesn't actually go through the glass in Cycles: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/68410/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2558/

Comment: You can't do that in blender. Caustics in cycles are quite limited, as is not a bidirectional path tracer. Try using LuxRender or other more advanced render engine.

Answer (score 1):

[LuxRender](https://luxcorerender.org/download/) shows refraction correctly.

1. Install LuxRender (currently support 2.82 and 2.83)
2. Setup a model with a refraction shader just like for Cycles
3. Render!

[image]

Sample Blend file - [image]